# Why using nested tables rather than REFs ? Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, nested-table

What are the nested tables used for ?

I think I understand both nested table and ref concepts.

However, I can't figure out the benefits of the nested vs the ref.

Is there better use cases for both ? How to know ?

Because personally I find the pointer system of ref more clear and organized.

Comment: Nobody **(\*)** uses nested tables or REFs in table definitions. Objects are fine for defining APIs and other program constructs, but data should be stored relationally. **(\*)**  okay, almost nobody.

Comment: @APC I 100% concur. I wish Oracle had never introduced nested tables or refs

Comment: It's not the answer to my question, but thank you for the advice I appreciate. I am studying it at uni, so I need to understand the purpose no matter what the real-life use is. Still waiting for the answer on the real difference between both !

Comment: "*What are the nested tables used for*" - in my opinion: nothing. Probably only by the marking department to have another check mark on the feature list. "*However, I can't figure out the benefits*" - me neither.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll pass over it, in the desert